# Let $\bar X_n$ be the sample mean. What is the accurate rate of $\bar X_n-\mu$ convergence to $0$,

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are samples from $X$. Let $\bar X_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Then it is well known that
$$\bar X_n\overset{p}\to\mu\qquad\qquad(1)$$
and
$$\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-\mu)\overset{d}\to N(0,\sigma^2)\qquad\qquad(2)$$

From $(1)$ we have $\bar X_n-\mu=o_p(1)$. From $(2)$ we have $\bar X_n-\mu=O_p(1/\sqrt{n})$.
My question is that can we derive the accurate rate of $\bar X_n-\mu$ convergence to $0$, say, $\bar X_n-\mu=o_p(n^\alpha)$?

Comment: You say "Suppose $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are samples from $X$. Let $\bar X_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$."  

Assuming you mean independent samples then, since each is normally distributed, you have $\bar X_n \sim N(\mu,\frac1n\sigma^2)$ and $\bar X_n - \mu \sim N(0,\frac1n\sigma^2)$ with no need for the Central Limit Theorem.  The standard error of the mean is then exactly $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you’re looking for is the law of iterated logarithm, which says for finite variance iid variables, $\frac{\bar X_n-\mu}{\sigma}\sim \frac{\sqrt{2\log\log n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ in the sense that the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of the ratio are $\pm 1$ almost surely.

Answer (score 1):

If the $X_i$ have finite variance, the CLT says that $n^{1/2} (\overline X_n - \mu) $ converges weakly, hence for any $0<\epsilon < \frac 12$,  $n^{1/2-\epsilon} (\overline X_n - \mu)  = o_p(1)$, that is  $$\overline X_n - \mu = o_p\left(\frac 1{n^{1/2-\epsilon}}\right)$$